# Angular ng-select multiple values in *ngFor directive

Tags: angular, iteration, ngfor

I have several [ng-select](https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/search) (Custom server-side search) dropdowns created by a *ngFor directive, having the possibility to pick multiple items from each dropdown.

The problem however is that each time I search for something and pick a value, that value will be selected for all the other ng-select dropdowns as well. Also I need to make the option values returned by the api **based** on the iteration's variable

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vml2j8

**filter.component.html**:

```
<div *ngFor="let filter of filters;index as i">
    <ng-select [items]="filterValues | async"
             [typeahead]="filterValuesInput"
             [multiple]="true"
             (open)="ngSelectOpened(filter.name)"
             [loading]="filterValuesLoading"
             bindLabel="name"
             [(ngModel)]="selectedFilterValues[pref.name]">
    </ng-select>
</div>
```

**filter.component.ts**

```
filterValues: Observable<FilterValues[]>;
filterValuesLoading = false;
filterValuesInput = new Subject<string>();
selectedFilterValues];

ngSelectOpened(filterName) {
    this.filterValues = concat(
      of([]), // default items
      this.filterValuesInput.pipe(
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        tap(() => this.filterValuesLoading = true),
        switchMap(term => this.dataService.getData(term).pipe(
          catchError(() => of([])), // empty list on error
          tap(() => this.filterValuesLoading = false)
        ))
      )
    );
}
```

How can I make the ng-select work based on current iteration?

Comment: `filterValues` is shared between all `ng-select` instances, so clearly when it changes all of them will contain the same list. You should change to  an array - `Observable<FilterValues[]>[]` instead, and identify/populate each by `filter.name`. As follows: `this.filterValues[filterName] = concat...`

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment! In order to get the filterName in the component ts, shouldn't I provide it in the template first?  `<ng-select [items]="filterValues[filter.name] | async"></ng-select>`

Comment: Yes you should of course

Comment: Unfortunately it gives me the error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Filter 1' of undefined`

Comment: As always, sharing your code in stackblitz is best. Meanwhile what line of code triggers this error messages?

Comment: I have other <select> element which I think is responsible for giving the error, but I'm not sure how? [![Capture.png](https://i.postimg.cc/wBCWZhbK/Capture.png)](https://postimg.cc/v1vL66sX)

Comment: It's a separate issue then?!

Comment: Can’t say w/o seeing the full code. But not related we your original message apparently

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Filter 1' of undefined is triggered by `[items]="filterValues$[pref.name] | async"`

Comment: Update the full code in the question body above. Both html and ts

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vml2j8

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not most elegant but seems to work. Previously your `selectedPersons` were shared between all lists.

Changed Html:

```
<div *ngFor="let pref of filters">
  <ng-select [items]="people$ | async"
            bindLabel="name"
            [addTag]="true"
            [multiple]="true"
            [hideSelected]="true"
            [trackByFn]="trackByFn"
            [minTermLength]="2"
            (open)="ngSelectOpened(pref.name)"
            [loading]="peopleLoading"
            typeToSearchText="Please enter 2 or more characters"
            [typeahead]="peopleInput$"
            [(ngModel)]="pref.selected">
  </ng-select>
  <br>
</div>
```

Changed ts (2 lists):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService, Person } from '../data.service';
import { concat, Observable, of, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  people$: Observable<Person[]>;
    peopleLoading = false;
    peopleInput$ = new Subject<string>();
    selectedPersons: Person[] = <any>[{ name: 'Karyn Wright' }, { name: 'Other' }];
    filters = [
        {id: 1, name: "Filter1", selected: [...this.selectedPersons]},
        {id: 2, name: "Filter2", selected: [...this.selectedPersons]}/*,
        {id: 3, name: "Filter3"}*/
    ]

    constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    }


    ngSelectOpened(filterName) {
      this.loadPeople(filterName);
    }

    private loadPeople(filterName) {
        this.people$ = concat(
            of([]), // default items
            this.peopleInput$.pipe(
                distinctUntilChanged(),
                tap(() => this.peopleLoading = true),
                switchMap(term => this.dataService.getPeople(term).pipe(
                    catchError(() => of([])), // empty list on error
                    tap(() => this.peopleLoading = false)
                ))
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, [ngModel] pointing to a different variable doesn't populate all the other dropdowns but there are still requests and loaders triggered even though I'm focusing on a single dropdown. Wasn't I supposed to change to an array? `Observable<FilterValues[]>[]`

Comment: Maybe `Observable<FilterValues[][]>`??. Experiment with all

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of data; let i=index">
 <ng-select id={{i}} name={{i}} class="custom" placeholder="Select" 
                         [items]="dataDropdown" bindLabel="Code" bindValue="Key"
                         [(ngModel)]="item.Key" [virtualScroll]="true" trim="blur"    (open)="ngSelectOpened(item.Nm)"
                         *ngIf="pageMode.toLocaleLowerCase() === 'add' || pageMode.toLocaleLowerCase() === 'edit'" autocomplete="off">
              </ng-select>
</ng-container>

ngSelectOpened(name: string) {
    this.dataDropdown = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.dynamicdropdown.filter(x => x.ratingAgencyNm === agencyname)))

  }
```

deep copied the dropdown values to another variable and filter it on ngfor loop through and updated the original dropdown variable on open event